# Matrix dimension do not mach in regression formula

Tags: math, matrix, machine-learning, regression, dimensions

I'm trying to calculate this [image] regression formula, but I have problem with the dimension calculation, they are not correct:
Where:

**X**-a matrix with dimensions **200x20**, n=200 samples, p=20 predictors,

**y**-a matrix with dimensions **200x1**,

[image] - a sequence of coefficients, dimensions **20x1**, and k=1,2,3...

[image]- dimensions **20x200**

**j**- and value from *1...p* so from **1...20**,

The problem is when I calculate [image]

For example for k=20, k-1=19 i have [image] and the dimensions do not match to do a substraction **200x1** - **200x20** x **1x1** =**200x1** - **200x20** will not work.

If I take all the beta vector then it is correct. does this: [image] mean to take the 19th value of *Beta* and to multiply it with the matrix X?

**[Source](http://www.stat.cmu.edu/~ryantibs/papers/stagewise.pdf) of the formula:**

[image]

Comment: Can you provide the source for the formula? It seems that if you use the entire 20x1 vector of beta coefficients then the dimensions will work. It's not at all clear to me what the meaning of the `k` is from what you have shown.

Comment: @myrtlecat done!

Comment: @myrtlecat yes the dimensions work when I use the entire Beta vector, but not when I take only a value of beta.

Comment: thank you it's clear now. It's clear to me that you should use the whole beta vector. I'll try to explain below but it's going to be a bit hard without latex!

Comment: @myrtlecat thank you, you could maybe use online latex: https://www.codecogs.com/latex/eqneditor.php

Comment: @myrtlecat could it maybe be that I have to use all the beta vector with zero values and just the k-1 as a non-zero value?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should be using the entire beta vector at each stage of the calculation.

(Tibshirani has been a bit permissive with his use of notation, perhaps...)

The `k` is just a counter for which step of the algorithm we are on. Right at the start (`k = 0` or "step 0") we initialise the entire beta vector to have all elements equal to zero: [image: step0]

At each step of the algorithm (steps `k = 1, 2, 3...` and so on) we use our previous estimate of the vector beta ([image] calculated in step `k - 1`) to calculate a new improved estimate for the vector beta ([image]). The superscript number is not an index into the vector, rather it is a label telling us at which stage of the algorithm that beta vector was produced.

I hope this makes sense. The important point is that each of the values [image] is a different 20x1 vector.